# Ошибка при чтении конфига configparser.ConfigParser: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 ..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

```
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
cfg.read(cfg_path+'/config.cfg')
a_text = configparser.ConfigParser()
a_text.read('data')
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "bot.py", line 70, in <module>
    a_text.read('data')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 696, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 1012, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Такая ошибка появляется только при запуске на сервере, на ПК все нормально. Возможно ошибка в локали.

Comment: Добавьте ваш код, например,  где у вас: `a_text.read('data')`. Хочу увидеть как вы объект конфига создаете. Кст, а почему вы не приняли ни одного ответа по своим вопросам?

Comment: @gil9red os.system('touch '+cfg_path+'/config.cfg'),  а файл data я создал вручную

Comment: @gil9red а как их принимать?)

Comment: @gil9red https://github.com/TheAngryPython/rpgbot/blob/master/bot.py

Comment: @gil9red теперь другая ошибка подобного рода. [!] error in (bot.py, line 632 "log('[@] @'+username+' ('+str(uid)+') requested '+text)"): 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 40-45: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @ТерновойЕгор, аналогично предыдущей проблеме в `log = open(cfg_path+'/log.txt', 'a')` укажите `encoding='utf-8'`: `log = open(cfg_path+'/log.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')`. А лучше вместо самописного логера используйте стандартный -- `logger`. Мой пример пишет и в консоль, и в файл: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/257e7549078edb6571f3704048ea099010faa4fd/logger_example.py#L7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема из-за того, что если не указывать кодировку, то при чтении конфига будет использоваться системная, что может проявиться ошибкой кодеков.

Например, на той машине, системная кодировка `ASCII` (это в трассе стека видно по названию модуля `ascii.py`):

```
a_text.read('data')
```

У метода [ConfigParser.read(filenames, encoding=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) есть параметр кодировки, укажите в нем:

```
a_text.read('data', encoding='utf-8')
```